# Force adding new rows with not used auto_increment IDs of older deleted rows

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's have an example:

```
id (auto_increment)   user
1                     John
2                     Mary
10                    Christopher
```

How do I force a query to add new `users` with not used `ids`? :In our case from 3 to 9:

Comment: why do you want to do like this?

Comment: This probably isn't as good an idea as you might think and would likely cause more problems than it solves.  Is there a reason you want this?  Why does it matter if all of the primary key values are contiguous?

Comment: If the OP expects to have a lot of users being created and deleted, it's conceivable he could eventually "run out" of new identity values for a 32-bit integer identity column, and he may not want to use 64-bit values. A batch process to "compact" existing IDs would be expensive and error prone. However, both of these concerns are pretty fringe; 2 *billion* users would have to be created before he'd even be close to having a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this with a bit of clever SQL by setting the ID of the record you wish to insert to the first "missing" ID value of the table:

```
INSERT INTO myTable (id, user) 
VALUES 
(
   (SELECT MIN(mt2.id)+1 from myTable mt2 WHERE NOT EXISTS 
         (SELECT 'Y' from myTable mt3 where mt3.Id = mt2.id + 1)), 
   'New User Name'
)
```

You may not be able to do this in one query, depending on DBMS. This approach also pretty much renders making the Id column an "auto-generate" column useless; this insert would always find the minimum value that didn't have an ID, whether that's the one the identity generator would try to use or not, and you would pretty much always have to enable "identity insert" before inserting to the table, so the auto-gen feature on this table would never be used.

Comment: The weaknesses of running this query are NlogN time complexity (the first subquery scans the table for all elements where the indexed subquery doesn't return a row), and the fact that it may not work on some DBMSes that don't take a subquery expression in insert statements. The ANSI standards don't require it (though most commersial DBMSes allow it).

Comment: I will run this query only at night, to not eat to many resources from the server during the day.

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `mytable` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `mytable` (`id`,`col1`) VALUES (1,'mydata');
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `mytable` ENABLE KEYS */;
```

A lot more simple IMO. As generated by MySQL Admin GUI tools.